# Remove "no newline at end of file" changes from git stage

Tags: git, sed, newline

I performed a sed search/replace on a large codebase, and for every file that sed passed over, it added a newline at the end if none was there previously. While it is good convention to end the last line with \n, this is a huge diff that is irrelevant to what I was trying to accomplish. The change affected hundreds of files, which I don't want to manually check and `git checkout` by hand.

Is there any way to selectively add or remove staged changes such that files that have only "no newline at end of file" will be ignored?

Comment: Perhaps you could do two commits: First one to add a \n to every file that doesn't have on already, and another to do what you're doing with sed; this should fix the problem once and for all...

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/questions/388276/prevent-diff-from-checking-for-newline-at-end-of-file

Comment: @Carpetsmoker - That would work, but first I'd have to separate the affected files into those with substantial changes and those with only the one change at the end to make the two commits. If I had taken your suggestion before doing any other work, it would have made things much easier.

Comment: @BenMorris If time is not of the essence, you could always rewind to a commit before your `sed` search/replace, and follow Carpetsmoker's advice. The beauty of Git is that you (almost) never have to tell yourself "I should have done that before...".

Comment: @Jubobs - that is definitely helpful. I can see only the files with significant changes with `git diff --ignore-all-space`. However, if I try to use `git diff --ignore-all-space --name-only` to get the list of files so I can add them to the stage, for some reason the list still includes files with only whitespace changes. It's close, but not quite working yet.

Comment: As for reverting to a previous commit, I actually had done some substantial work on this branch before using sed that I'd prefer not to lose...

Comment: @BenMorris Do you mean that you have other valuable changes in the last commit (the head of your branch)? Or that you have valuable commits in its ancestors? In the latter case, you could just do a `git reset --hard HEAD^` to forget about your last commit.

Comment: I had important unstaged, uncommitted changes when I ran sed, so those changes along with a bunch of insignificant whitespace changes all exist locally and not on any commit yet.

Comment: @BenMorris For future reference: it's better to have logically separate commits. You can always decide to squash them later if you don't care about a high level of detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the linked related issue, I found that `git diff --ignore-all-space` would ignore files with only whitespace changes. `git diff --ignore-all-space --name-only` doesn't work as I expected it to, but this does:

`git diff --ignore-all-space | grep "+++"`

This gave me a list of files that have changes other than whitespace, which is small enough that I can just add them all manually to the stage and commit.

Thanks to everyone for the comments, they were very helpful.

Comment: I think you're thinking of `--ignore-all-space`

Answer (score 0):

What I did differs a bit from @BenMorris's solution, which finds files that *only* have the whitespace difference and no other changes.  I wanted to discard the EOF newline change even if there are other valid changes in the same file:

To get a list of files with such differences:

```
git diff | grep '\(+++\|No newline at\)' | grep -B 1 'No newline at'
```

...or if your grep supports it, this will clean up the output to give just the paths:

```
git diff | grep '\(+++\|No newline at\)' | grep -B 1 'No newline at' | grep --perl-regexp -o '\+\+\+ b/\K.*'
```

That's enough to just point you to which files to clean up manually, but  to automate the rest of the process....

Download and install  [splitpatch.rb](https://github.com/jaalto/splitpatch) if you don't have it

Make a complete patch of all staged changes in all files with EOF newline changes.  (This includes a couple of grep -v's to avoid small issues with compatibility between git and the output of splitpatch.)

```
git diff --cached | grep '\(+++\|No newline at\)' | grep -B 1 'No newline at' | grep -Po '\+\+\+ b/\K.*' | xargs git  diff --cached   | grep -v "^diff --git a" | grep -v "^index "   > fullpatch.patch
```

Break it up into hunks:

```
/path/to/splitpatch.rb --hunk fullpatch.patch
```

This creates separate numbered files named Filename.extention.00#.patch, starting from 000.  Apply, in reverse, only the last (highest-numbered) patch for each source file (The line below is bash-only, not zsh, due to a difference in globbing):

```
for f0 in *.000.patch; do (for f_all in ${f0/000/*}; do echo $f_all;  done) | tail -n -1;  done | xargs -n 1 git apply —reverse
```

It's not impossible there could be a "real" change caught in the same hunk with the EOF newline, so take a look with `git diff` and use an editor to undo any changes besides the last line.

Clean up:

```
ls *.patch
rm *.patch
```

When you add these small reverse changes to the index, you will have discarded the newline changes at EOF.